# This self-left-join is returning more records than I expected it to

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

[SQL fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00935/1)

Hopefully my goal is clear: I've got a table that stores a "from" currency, a "to" currency, a "buying" and "selling" exchange rate, and the date that the rate should apply from.

*I want to get a list of the latest exchange rates for all currencies, up to a given cutoff date.*

That means that:

1. the results should include ONE row for each combination* of "from"
   and "to" currency, and
2. if there's more than one row in the table
   with that particular combination of "from" and "to" currency the row
   fetched should be the one with the most recent date.

The query that I'm using doesn't do that. In fact, it currently seems to return everything.

```
SELECT ce.*
FROM currency_exchange ce
LEFT JOIN currency_exchange newer
    ON (
        newer.currency_from = ce.currency_from
        AND newer.currency_to = ce.currency_to
        AND newer.exchange_date > ce.exchange_date
        AND newer.exchange_date <= '2012-03-27 00:00:00'
    )
WHERE newer.id IS NULL
ORDER BY ce.currency_from, ce.currency_to, ce.exchange_date DESC
```

*Just to clarify: I'm counting "from" and "to" currencies as mutually exclusive. If there's a row in the database that specifies a rate from currency ID 123, to currency ID 321, and another row specifies a rate from currency ID 321, to currency ID 123, both of those rows should be returned. Yes, the buying rate from 123 to 321 will logically be equivalent to the selling rate from 321 to 123, and vice versa.

Comment: I notice that my vague and misleading tags have been updated for me, and now much better summarise the question content: I've also learnt that the type of query I'm looking for is commonly referred to as "greatest-n-per-group". Is there a good resource available online that briefly describes these common SQL query patterns? Being able to describe problems in the correct terms is a huge step towards getting useful help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many way on how solve this particular problem. The one I used is by using a subquery which gets the current *exchange date* for every combination of *currency_from, currency_to*. The result of the subquery is only 3 columns and that's the reason why we need to join it on the original table table to get the remaining columns, provided that it matches with: `currency_from`, `currency_to`, and `exchange_date`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    currency_exchange a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  currency_from, currency_to, MAX(exchange_date) max_date
            FROM    currency_exchange
            GROUP   BY currency_from, currency_to
        ) b ON  a.currency_from = b.currency_from AND
                a.currency_to = b.currency_to AND
                a.exchange_date = b.max_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00935/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ CURRENCY_FROM ║ CURRENCY_TO ║ RATE_IN ║ RATE_OUT ║    EXCHANGE_DATE    ║
╠════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 20 ║             1 ║           2 ║ 1.43    ║ 1.65     ║ 2013-03-05 15:55:29 ║
║ 19 ║             1 ║           3 ║ 1.1     ║ 1.26     ║ 2013-03-05 15:49:45 ║
║ 16 ║             2 ║           3 ║ 2       ║ 3        ║ 2012-11-16 15:44:33 ║
╚════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks like what I'm after. Just to clarify: where should the cutoff date constraint appear in this query? As a WHERE clause in the subquery, or as an additional part of the JOIN? Or does it not matter?

Comment: add a `WHERE` on the subquery because the subquery get's the final rows. the result for having an outer query is just to get the remaining columns..

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli what do you mean by table structure? `DESC tableName`